# bbcode php code and highlighted source code using a php or javascript library

Tags: php, regex, syntax-highlighting, bbcode

I have a custom php website where I want to post php snippets but I'd like to have highlight my source code. I tried via pure php using `Geshi` (https://github.com/GeSHi/geshi-1.0) but it's not as I wanted, so I'm interested in other library like `Google Code Prettify` (https://github.com/google/code-prettify) but I don't know how using this javascript library.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="gcp/prettify.css">
<script src="gcp/prettify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body onload="prettyPrint()">

$body = preg_replace('#\[code\](.*)\[/code\]#isU', '<div class="code"><span class="xcode"><code class="prettyprint">\1</code></span></div>', $body);
```

Am I using correctly `Google Code Prettify`?

Another question, am I using the correct `Regular Expression` in the `bbcode`?

Any help is appreciated!

[image: example]

Comment: Stack Overflow uses [Google Code Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) for syntax highlighting. You might find it easier to use than the PHP solution your trying.

Comment: Great!!! I solved my problem by following your suggestion!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better function to use would be [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for this as you can then pass the matched text to a callback function for reformatting.

Here's an example implementation: (this may need some tweaking but you should get the idea)

```
function code_tag_replace( $matches ) {
    $ret  = '<TABLE WIDTH="100%" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="10" CLASS="code" BORDER="0"><TR><TD><SPAN CLASS="xcode">';
    $ret .= SyntaxHighlight::process( $matches[1] );
    $ret .= '</SPAN></TD></TR></TABLE>';
    return $ret;
}
$body = preg_replace_callback(
    '#\[code\](.*)\[/code\]#isU',
    'code_tag_replace',
    $body
);
```

Comment: Under php 5.3 invalid opcode 153/1/8. in W:\www\pst\conf.php on line 356 on **function( $matches ) {** Under php 5.4 **error loading page**... preg_replace_callback make crash apache & php... under php 5.4...

Comment: AeroX can you explain better what do you mean? Try giving me some example if you can, please...

Comment: function space2nbsp($matches) {
      $s = $matches[0];
      return str_repeat('&nbsp;', strlen($s));
    }
    $body = preg_replace_callback('/\s{2,}/', 'space2nbsp', $body); on my php configuration preg_replace_callback must be called after, first must go the function... this is another example taken from my php file that I use for posting...

Comment: @user3584233 I believe the example I gave should now work for you. It appears your version of PHP doesn't support [`Anonymous Functions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). I've also changed `$matches[0]` to `$matches[1]` which should only pass the first sub-pattern to `SyntaxHighlight` instead of the entire match.